# I can't change range and/or default values in DevExpress Dashboard

Tags: sql-server, xml, visual-studio-2015, devexpress, dashboard

I have a page where users register and can make their personal diet plan etc.
I am trying to make some graphs with built-in VS dashboards.
I am using VS 2015 and SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18206.0 if that matters.

My problems are the following:

1. Automatic (SUM)

Dashboard values default to SUM function, which I am not able to change, as you see in the first picture, but I kind of managed to solve this problem with the help of SQL (SELECT DISTINCT, SELECT TOP(1) etc.)

[Automatic (SUM)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH1Pj.png)

2. Default year count

When I am trying to make a dashboard to show track of user's vitals and activity, which is the core of my statistics, time defaults to YEAR and the result end up like the second picture.

[Default year count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYHk9.png)

There is nothing I can do to change these and I just made irrelevant graphs to fill the page, but it's a shame because I planned to make a lot of graphs with the table you see in the third picture.

[User History table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hoqP.png)

If it helps, the XML code generated from the last dashboard is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Dashboard>
  <Title Text="YearDashBoard" />
  <DataSources>
    <SqlDataSource ComponentName="DataSource1">
      <Name>UserHistory1</Name>
      <Connection Name="foodConnectionString" FromAppConfig="true" />
      <Query Type="SelectQuery" Name="UserHistory1" Distinct="true">
        <Tables>
          <Table Name="UserHistory" />
        </Tables>
        <Columns>
          <Column Table="UserHistory" Name="CaloriesDate" />
          <Column Table="UserHistory" Name="DailyCalories" />
          <Column Table="UserHistory" Name="UserID" />
        </Columns>
        <Filter>[UserHistory.UserID] = 17</Filter>
      </Query>
      <ConnectionOptions CloseConnection="true" CommandTimeout="0" />
    </SqlDataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <Items>
    <Chart ComponentName="chartDashboardItem1" Name="Chart 1" DataSource="DataSource1" DataMember="UserHistory1">
      <DataItems>
        <Measure DataMember="DailyCalories" DefaultId="DataItem0" />
        <Dimension DataMember="CaloriesDate" DefaultId="DataItem1" />
      </DataItems>
      <Arguments>
        <Argument DefaultId="DataItem1" />
      </Arguments>
      <Panes>
        <Pane Name="Pane 1">
          <Series>
            <Simple>
              <Value DefaultId="DataItem0" />
            </Simple>
          </Series>
        </Pane>
      </Panes>
    </Chart>
  </Items>
  <LayoutTree>
    <LayoutGroup Weight="100">
      <LayoutItem DashboardItem="chartDashboardItem1" Weight="100" />
    </LayoutGroup>
  </LayoutTree>
</Dashboard>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with the help of DevExpress technical team, I found out that the whole time there was an invisible scroll bar, but you had to mouse over it (!) while being on the "BINDING" tab of the menu.